# Layout of panels with splitters

Tags: delphi, layout, delphi-2007

I have a question about layout with TPanels and TcxSplitter from DevExpress.
[panellayout http://pp.kpnet.fi/bengtsson/temp/layout.png](http://pp.kpnet.fi/bengtsson/temp/layout.png)

The main form has some panels A to G. A - F is collected in one panel ABCDEF.
ABCDEF contains 3 panels:
AB, CDE and F.
Panel CDE contains panel CD.

Between all limits between panels there are a TcxSplitter from DevExpress.
The problem is that the user can take the splitter between ABCDEF and G and move it to left so it reach panel AB and cover panel CDE. I don't want to allow that.

Instead I want panel CDE have a minimum width of say 5 pixels. Then the width of panel AB should be shrinked. Hopefully I explained good enough :)
I have tried to set a constraint.minwidth = 5 on panel CDE but the panel can still be hided. Maybe Devexpress have some nice solution for this ?

Regards

Comment: Wow. I'm just amazed that you have come so far with this splitter at all. The splitter component may be the least 'workable' component in the vcl. I would suggest that you take a look at raize components splitterpanel instead. I find it much easier to work with.

Comment: This is just an annoying glitch and in overall I am satisfied with the Devexpress component suite. The application use them a lot mostly for grids.

Comment: I though dxSplitter was just a prettier version of the included vcl splitter. Does the dxSplitter work any different then the standard vcl splitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cxSplitter has MinSize property, from what I see in a test app, it is respected when resizing. Since there is only 1 MinSize property, it is checked for panels on either side of splitter, so you can't specify say 50 pixels minimum for one side and 100 for the panel on the other side of the splitter. Make sure the AutoSnap property is false though.

But there is also a OnCanResize event on the splitter, so you can prevent resize there as well.

Also, since you're using devex I would suggest you use either dockSite/dockPanel or LayoutControl v2 instead of plain Delphi TPanel.

Comment: I use the OnCanResize event and prevent resizing over the limit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this property

```
cxSplitter1.ResizeUpdate:=True;
```